# Use of php variable $_ (dollar sign followed by an underscore)

Tags: php, loops, variables, foreach, naming-conventions

Is that **really** true that i can use `$_` as a dummy variable in `foreach` loop if there is no need for `$value` in `foreach($array as $key => $value)`? I could not find any useful information that proves this except [PHP syntax formatting](http://docs.typo3.org/TYPO3/CodingGuidelinesReference/PhpFileFormatting/PhpSyntaxFormatting/Index.html).

> There's a special case for foreach loops when the value is not used
>   inside the loop. In this case the dummy variable $_ (underscore) is
>   used:
>
> `foreach ($GLOBALS['TCA'] as $table => $_) { // Do something with $table }`
>
> This is done for performance reasons, as it is faster than calling
>   array_keys() and looping on its result.

Comment: take less time to test than ask

Comment: Have you tried `foreach(array_keys($GLOBALS['TCA']) as $table)` ?  Granted, it's probably less resource intensive to just have the unused values variable.

Comment: I actually have an `array($key => $arrayforlateruse, ... , ...)`. `$arrayforlateruse` is variable not needed right now. Now i know that placing `$_` instead has no effect.

Comment: Makes me wish there was a convention in PHP for using `$_` for situations like this where a variable has to be provided, but it won't be used - similar as in Go, however in Go an unused variable leads to an error; PHP doesn't have to be that strict, but using `$_` could be a signal for linters and IDEs that a variable is intentionally not used, and they could disable the "unused variable" warning for this variable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"_" is a **valid variable name character**, so you can use it as you would any other variable and has no special significance; this isn't Perl.

```
<?php
    $_ = "Hello";
    $__ = "World";
    $___ = "foo";

    print "{$_}, {$__}, {$___}\n";
?>
```

will output "Hello, World, foo" as expected. Also,

```
foreach ( [ 'a' => 'Alpha', 'b' => 'Beta', 'c' => 'Gamma' ] as $letter => $_ ) {
    print $letter;
}
print $_;
```

will output "abcGamma", showing that the `$_` variable remains defined after being used in the `foreach`; it's not some weird kind of "local" variable.

As for the performances, I don't think it makes much difference, but that's your call. Rather, I'd try and not use global variables, to avoid polluting the global scope.

## Tests and rants more or less at random

**TL;DR** *go with `foreach()`*.

*feel free to correct/add/suggest improvements*

```
define('INNER_LOOP', 10000);
define('OUTER_LOOP', 10);

$TCA    = [
    'customers' => '',
    'relations' => '',
    'invoices'  => '',
    'books'     => '',
    'parts'     => '',
    'records'   => '',
    'calories'  => '',
    'bounties'  => '',
    'cats'      => '',
    'cowabunga' => '',
    'amenities' => '',
];

$tests  = [
    "foreach access to global" => function() {
        global $TCA;
        for ($i = 0; $i < INNER_LOOP; $i++) {
            foreach ($TCA as $table => $_) {
                $t = $table . 'x';
            }
        }
    },
    "foreach access to GLOBALS" => function() {
        for ($i = 0; $i < INNER_LOOP; $i++) {
            foreach ($GLOBALS['TCA'] AS $table => $_) {
                $t = $table . 'x';
            }
        }
    },
    "passing parameter" => function($TCA) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < INNER_LOOP; $i++) {
            foreach ($TCA AS $table => $_) {
                $t = $table . 'x';
            }
        }
    },
    "passing parameter and array_keys" => function($TCA) {
        $keys = array_keys($TCA);
        for ($i = 0; $i < INNER_LOOP; $i++) {
            foreach ($keys AS $table) {
                $t = $table . 'x';
            }
        }
    },
    "walking passed parameter w/lambda" => function($TCA) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < INNER_LOOP; $i++) {
            array_map(
                function($table) {
                    $t = $table . 'x';
                },
                array_keys($TCA)
            );
        }
    },
    "walking passed parameter w/ anon func" => function($TCA) {
        $handler = function($table) {
                    $t = $table . 'x';
                };
        $keys = array_keys($TCA);
        for ($i = 0; $i < INNER_LOOP; $i++) {
            array_map($handler, $keys);
        }
    },


];

function timeFunc($function, $obj) {
  $time   = microtime(true);
  for ($i = 0; $i < OUTER_LOOP; $i++) {
    $function($obj);
  }
  return (microtime(true) - $time);
}

foreach ($tests as $name => $test) {
    print "$name: " . timeFunc($test, $TCA) . "\n";
    flush();
}
```

These are my results, formatted and sorted:

```
- passing parameter and array_keys:      0.04573917388916
- foreach access to global:              0.067629098892212
- passing parameter:                     0.08098292350769
- foreach access to GLOBALS:             0.082289934158325
- walking passed parameter w/ anon func: 1.6233508586884
- walking passed parameter w/lambda:     1.6796138286591
```

Two things need noting: between the fastest and slowest I have a difference of about *forty times*. **But** the difference over **one hundred thousand calls** is 1.63 seconds, which means 16.3 **microseconds** for a single call between the faster and the slower versions.

So if one of these versions show promise of saving you, say, five minutes a year of head-scratching, bug-hunting or customer support, it's likely that going for *that* version will prove a worthwhile investment.

If, on the other hand, you really need something called several *billion* times, so that those paltry microseconds add up to something worth tackling, then probably you'd be better off investing some time in porting (or having ported) that section of code to a language which is either inherently faster or can be made to massively parallelize - maybe C, or Erlang; or re-thinking the architecture (e.g. daemonize a process to save on the overhead, use stored procedures to offload the hassle to the RDBMS, cache results, ...).

## UPDATE FOR PHP 7.2

These are the results for PHP 7.2.19 on a newer 64bit machine:

```
passing parameter and array_keys        0.57718586921692
foreach access to global                0.65028595924377
passing parameter                       0.65098810195923
foreach access to GLOBALS               0.69678092002869
walking passed parameter w/ anon func   0.84391593933105
walking passed parameter w/lambda       1.0423438549042
```

Note that the difference between fastest and slowest is now less than a factor of 2; therefore, the argument for "go with the clearest, easiest to understand code" is now even stronger.

## Update for PHP 8.1.2

```
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2023 11:41:11) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans

$results = [];
foreach ($tests as $name => $test) {
    $results[$name] = number_format(timeFunc($test, $TCA), 5);
}

asort($results);
$fastest = 0;
foreach ($results as $name => $result) {
    if (0 === $fastest) {
        $fastest = $result;
    }
    print "{$name}: {$result}\n";
}

printf("Slowest/Fastest ratio = %.2f\n", $result/$fastest);
```

The machine *should* be the same as the one that ran the 7.x tests, unless my memory's gone; so I don't understand why all functions are markedly faster. However, I increased the INNER_LOOP by a factor of ten.

```
passing parameter and array_keys: 0.19822
passing parameter               : 0.24471
foreach access to global        : 0.24732
foreach access to GLOBALS       : 0.24866
walking passed param w/ anon fn : 1.25215
walking passed param w/lambda   : 1.36373

Slowest/Fastest ratio = 6.88
```

I've added a *static function* test using the new "short" function available to PHP:

```
array_map(
    static fn($table) => $table + 'x',
    array_keys($TCA)
)
```

which times at 1.22284, that can be shaved to 1.1576 by caching `array_keys($TCA)` into `$keys`. So, while useful and marginally better than straight lambda, the short form isn't really a game changer performance-wise.

Answer (score 2):

From [Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable. The variable name is case-sensitive.
>
> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

So `$_` is just an arbitrary variable. There's really no difference between using `$_` and `$value`, except that `$_` is just a conventional way to indicate a value that is not actually used inside the loop.

Notice that this

```
$foo = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
foreach ($foo as $key => $_) echo $_;
```

Outputs

```
123
```

Answer (score 2):

The test below demonstrates that using `$_` as a variable name in this situation doesn't seem to be any different from using any other variable name. The value is still stored in the variable.

```
$tmp = array(1=>"one", 2=>"two", 3=>"three", 4=>"four", 5=>"five");
foreach ($tmp as $num=>$_) {
        echo "num is $num; dummy is $_<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated `$_` is a valid variable name.  This seems to be Typo3 coding guidelines though the `$_` is not being used, but the value variable is required for the `foreach`.  Why loop the values if you don't need the values but the keys?  That looks hackish.  You can get the keys as values.  I would just use:

```
foreach (array_keys($GLOBALS['TCA']) as $table) {
    // Do something with $table
}
```

Comment: "Why foreach if you don't need the value?" ...and yet you're still using a `foreach`.

Comment: Yes, and I am getting the `value`.