# What does the $_ (dollar underscore) variable mean?

Tags: php, naming-conventions

In PHP, what does `$_` mean as a variable or argument? Example:

```php
$myFunc = function ($a, $_) {
    return $a++;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of php variable $\_ (dollar sign followed by an underscore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046586/use-of-php-variable-dollar-sign-followed-by-an-underscore)

Comment: yep thanks. it's a difficult one to google.

Comment: It's worth noting that `$_` doesn't do anything at all in the snippet you've shared and could be removed without consequences. It's probably a placeholder the author added to remind himself that the callback function accepts up to two arguments.

Comment: @alvaro Yes, it is included as a placeholder to help make clear that the function is being passed two parameters even though it is only usine one argument in this case. The convention for this is to name the unused argument `$_`, but I wasn't sure if that was merely a convention or if that variable name had special meaning in PHP.